# Custom mapping the scope of an Angular fragment

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

My mind is still in the WPF world and I'm stepping into the Angular.JS one, which exposes several analogies. However, I can't figure out how to (whereas possible) "remap" the scope of a fragment, in order to better reuse templates.

Consider this example:

```
  <html ng-app="myApp">
  <body>
    <div id="container" ng-controller="ContentCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="item in content">
            <a href='#' ng-click="select(item)">{{item.title}}</a>
        </div>
        <hr>

        <!-- here is the target fragment -->
        <div ng-whatever="??? func(selected)">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <div ng-include="mapper($scope)"></div>
        </div>

   </div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="entry-photo">
        <div>
            <span><a href="{{data}}"><img ng-src="{{data}}"></a></span>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="entry-video">
        <div>
            <iframe ng-src="{{data}}" width="280" height="200" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="entry-notes">
        <div>{{data}}</div>
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

and the related script:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function ContentCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selected = null;
    $scope.content = [
        {"content_type" : "image", "title" : "Image 00", "data" : "http://www.letsgodigital.org/html/review/panasonic/lumix-dmc-fx33/photography/panasonic-fx33_small8.jpg"},
        {"content_type" : "video", "title" : "Video 00", "data" : "http://player.vimeo.com/video/37176398"},
        {"content_type" : "notes", "title" : "Notes 00", "data" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pulvinar pretium felis. Vivamus nibh felis, condimentum sit amet laoreet luctus, posuere auctor lorem. Nullam malesuada."}
    ];

    $scope.select = function(e){
        $scope.selected = e;
    };

    $scope.mapper = function(e){
        switch(e.content_type){
            case "image": return "entry-photo";
            case "video": return "entry-video";
            case "notes": return "entry-notes";
        }
    };
}
```

Of course the above markup is *NOT* working, clearly because is depicted as pseudo-code:

```
        <div ng-whatever="??? func(selected)">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <div ng-include="mapper($scope)"></div>
        </div>
```

I'd like to create a "custom scope" (derived from the original one), so that any descending node will inherit the remapped value. In this sample, the function could be simply the value of the "selected" property has.

Is there any simple way to achieve it?

Let's say I'm more interested to learn, rather to any totally different workaround. Since in WPF similar situations are very common yet simple to solve, I'm wondering how to do in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understood, what do you want, you can just declare another controller and it will create new scope.
From child scope you can get value from the parent scope with `$scope.$parent` object.

More details about AngularJS scopes you will find here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

This is my simple example.

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    {{name}}
    <div ng-controller="NestedCtrl">
        {{title}}
        <br/>
        {{$parent.name}}
    </div>
</div>

function ParentCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Parent';
}

function NestedCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Nested';
}
```

This is **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shepard_one/HB7LU/10293/)** for you.

Comment: I was afraid that my example were not the best one, and that is...
My goal is to define "components" over an "interface". If I use $parent with a component, it would be lead to know where is placed. Try to think the inner div of your snippet as a fragment which can be used somewhere else, as long the $scope exposes the properties used.

Comment: @MarioVernari, You want to use this component anywhere only just as html template, or you want to use parent scope's data also?

Comment: my real case isn't simple as above. The templates are files (views) pulled from the server, and used in one or more different ways on the web page. If you like, think a template as a "frame", where the caller provide just the URI. The frame content does not anything about it visual/logical parent...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code

```
$scope.mapper = function(e){
    switch(e.content_type){
        case "image": return "entry-photo";
        case "video": return "entry-video";
        case "notes": return "entry-notes";
    }
};
```

expects that e will be an item, not the $scope that u pass

```
ng-include="mapper($scope)"
```

so

```
ng-include="mapper()"
```

and

```
$scope.mapper = function(){
    if($scope.selected !== null) {
        switch($scope.selected.content_type){
            case "image": return "entry-photo";
            case "video": return "entry-video";
            case "notes": return "entry-notes";
        }
    } else {
        return "blank-tpl";
    }
};
```

and about scope, your directive will work in controller scope, so u can use in your templates selected variable like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="entry-notes">
    <div>{{selected.data}}</div>
</script>
```

and thats all.

Ofcourse if u dont want to use your controller scope u can write directive with own scope containing parent scope or isolated scope, se more in docs.

Comment: I don't want to downvote you, but that's NOT what I'm asking. I definitely want to *separate* the various sections, so that they may be changed independently. The "mapper($scope)" is clearly wrong, but I didn't know how to make my goal be understood.

Comment: If u want to separate template just make a directive with isolated scope, and define attributes that u want to pass into your template. One of attributes can be path to your template that u want to render

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what your asking for:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2441-nested-views-routing-and-deep-linking-with-angularjs.htm

You can also use directives:
http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/

You can also share data between controllers by defining a factory(often called a service). Multiple controllers are optional:
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers

And directive templates can either be includes (see below) or html string (as the second link):
http://www.portlandwebworks.com/blog/testing-angularjs-directives-handling-external-templates

Comment: Some of these I've already read: useful, but not directly related to my problem. Instead found this one, and seems doing exactly what I want (still testing, though): https://github.com/adjohnson916/ng-scope